# Can I install linux has the host in a dell poweredge server (r710)?

Tags: linux, dell-poweredge, firmware

I might have a deal on dual six core poweredge server and I'm about to go test its performance but I'm wondering few things which I can't find answers for, and I can't test them before buying the machine.

- I don't want vmware at all so can I just wipe it and install linux instead, or is it embedded in some parts I have no access to.
- Will I still be able to update different firmwares (perc controllers, motherboard, etc) on this dell poweredge or does it require to have the vmware esxi installed as the host os.

And optionally.. is there any foreseeable problems in doing so?

Comment: Do it, it'll work.

Comment: The fact that there are Linux drivers/firmware/etc available for download at http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/04/Product/poweredge-r710 should be a big hint that it is supported.

Comment: Thanks Petter & Zoredache. I saw that there is a linux filter showing 71 files but it still contains .exe and some binaries. I asked here because I trust admins and users experience more then big companies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**Dell PowerEdge R710**](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/R710-SpecSheet.pdf) is a standard mainline manufacturer server platform. You can install whatever you wish on it. It's supported by Linux, Windows, VMware, etc., as the drivers are standard.

You won't have any problems managing firmware, updates and drivers if you run Linux on this system. Be sure to install the [Dell management agents for Linux](http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/OMSA) on the server.